# How can I know the position of a specific element

Tags: jquery

I have the following `HTML`

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li id="369833" class="ui-state-default">
    <li id="372915" class="ui-state-default">
    <li id="276520" class="ui-state-default" style="">
    <li id="373229" class="ui-state-default">
    <li id="373231" class="ui-state-default">
    <li id="373253" class="ui-state-default">
</ul>
```

I can sort my `<li>` elements but I need know the position of a specific `<li>` that I sort.

**Exemple**

If I put in my console `$("#sortable").find("li").size()`, I have the return of the numbers of `<li>` are in my `<ul>`, 6 in this case. But how can I know the position of a specific `<li>` like, the `<li>` with the `id` 373231, where this `<li>` are inside my `<ul>` ? The return that I want is the number 5, because he is the fifth `<li>` element in my `<ul>`

**UPdate**

My function

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            debugger;

            // Getting a WRONG Position
            alert($(this).index());
        }
    });

    $("#sortable").on("sortstop", function (event, ui) {       

        // Getting a WRONG Position                         
        alert($(this).index());
    });

    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is  what you need here..

```
$(selector).index().
```

In your case

```
$('#369833').index(). //will give u 0
$('#372915').index(). //will give u 1
```

**EDITED**

take the index of the `ui.item`

```
alert(ui.item.index());
```

hers is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgsPu/)

Comment: Look at my Update. How can I apply this in my case ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)**, it is zero based so you will get `0` for `first` element and `1` for `second` so on.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wRyb/)**

```
$('#373231').index()
```

Comment: Look at my Update. How can I apply this in my case ?